# Перерисовка элементов Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

Доброго времени суток!

У меня есть JPanel. На ней отрисовываются 2 разных объекта, которые меняют своё местоположение. Меняют они своё положение в разные промежутки времени.

Под каждый объект выделен метод. Вот один из методов:

```
void drawPoint(Point point) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                Graphics g = getGraphics();
                g.drawImage(getImage(), point.getX(), point.getY(), this);
            });
        }
```

При таком раскладе он рисует дополнительные элементы, не стирая старые. Но если добавить перед `g.drawImage()`:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

то один из объектов рисуется как надо, но при этом стирается второй. Если оба метода будут использовать `super.paintComponent(g)`, то тоже ничего не выйдет.

Так вот сам вопрос: Как можно их отрисовывать корректно по отдельности, при условии что это надо делать в разные промежутки времени: один чаще
, другой реже? И возможно ли это вообще?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `paintComponent(g)` перерисовывает весь компонент. Он может быть вызван самой JVM в любое время когда это необходимо, например, при изменении размера окна.

Вызывая `super.paintComponent(g)` перед `g.drawImage()` ты стираешь все что было до этого, соответственно, первый/второй объект стирается и ты рисуешь новый объект.

Как вариант, ты можешь переопределить метод `paintComponent(g)` у JPanel и писать код для отрисовки объектов там. Для всех объектов. После в нужный момент, когда какой-нибудь объект меняет свое положение вызывать метод `repaint()` у JPanel.

Например,

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    private Point point1;
    private Point point2;

    MyPanel() {
        super();
        point1 = new Point(0, 0);
        point2 = new Point(270, 0);

        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                point1.x += 10;
                point1.y += 10;
                point2.x -= 10;
                point2.y += 10;
                MyPanel.this.repaint();
            }
        }, 0, 500);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawOval(point1.x, point1.y, 10, 10);
        g.drawOval(point2.x, point2.y, 10, 10);
    }
}

class Window extends JFrame {
    Window() {
        super("Title");

        setSize(300, 300);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        MyPanel panel = new MyPanel();
        getContentPane().add(panel);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new Window().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

[image: ""]>